# How to scale game on different orientations and screens

Tags: javascript, game-engine, game-development, phaser-framework, screen-orientation

I am trying to scale my game on different orientations( landscape and portrait ) but I face problems in keeping the game out of bugs, I am using javascript and mainly phaser.

I am trying to find a solution or any one expert that could advice on how to make a game with landscape and portraite mode, I used the resize function and edit every image individually but I feel that it is not the efficient way, I just want to scale the game on multiple devices and orientations as Unity do but using javascript, you can find my resize function that will be called every time when screen resized, the following code explain how the game goes even thought I think that when I do this I could affect many function when I rotate the screen and play.

```
resize() {

console.log('resize')
let width;
if (this.scale.isPortrait) {
  width = 1080;

} else {
  width = 1920;

}

this.scaleW = window.innerWidth / width;

this.worldWidth = window.innerWidth;
this.worldHeight = window.innerHeight;
this.worldCenterX = this.worldWidth / 2;
this.worldCenterY = this.worldHeight / 2;

// this.cameras.main.setZoom(this.scaleW*2)
this.stopTweening()
this.bg.setPosition(this.worldCenterX, this.worldCenterY)
// this.table.setScale(this.scaleW)
// .setPosition(0,0)
this.containerOfTable.setPosition(this.worldCenterX, this.worldCenterY)
let leftDistance = this.containerOfTable.getBounds().left / 2;
let rightDistance = this.containerOfTable.getBounds().right + (this.worldWidth - this.containerOfTable.getBounds().right) / 2;
let topDistance = this.containerOfTable.getBounds().top / 2;
let tableCenter = this.containerOfTable.getBounds()
let bottomDistance = this.containerOfTable.getBounds().bottom + (this.worldHeight - this.containerOfTable.getBounds().bottom) / 2;


let sharedCardsConfig = { y: bottomDistance, originX: 0, originY: 0.5, scaleX: this.scaleW, scaleY: 0 }
let cardsMarginX = 10 * this.scaleW;


this.timer.setScale(this.scaleW)
  .setPosition(this.table.getTopRight().x - 30 * this.scaleW, this.table.getTopRight().y + 20 * this.scaleW,)

this.button.setScale(this.scaleW)
  .setPosition(this.worldWidth - 20, 30)
for (let i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
  let player = this.players[i].setScale(this.scaleW)

  if (i == 0) {
    let khan = player.setPosition(tableCenter.centerX, 0).setOrigin(0.5, 0)
    if (this.scale.isLandscape) {

    }
  }
  else if (i == 1) {
    player.setPosition(leftDistance, tableCenter.centerY)

  }
  else if (i == 2) {
    player.setPosition(rightDistance, tableCenter.centerY)

  } else if (i == 3) {
    player.setPosition(20 * this.scaleW, 20 * this.scaleW)
  }
  else if (i == 4) {
    player.setPosition(this.players[2].getBottomCenter().x, this.players[2].getBottomCenter().y + 15 * this.scaleW)

  }
  else if (i == 5) {
    player.setPosition(this.players[1].getBottomCenter().x, this.players[1].getBottomCenter().y + 3 * this.scaleW)

  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
  let player = this.cards[i].setScale(this.scaleW).setOrigin(0, 0.5)

  if (i == 0) {
    player.setPosition(this.worldCenterX + cardsMarginX, sharedCardsConfig.y)
    cardsMarginX = this.cards[0].displayWidth + 20 * this.scaleW;

  }
  else if (i == 1) {
    player.setPosition(this.worldCenterX - cardsMarginX, sharedCardsConfig.y)


  }
  else if (i == 2) {
    player.setPosition(this.cards[0].x + cardsMarginX, sharedCardsConfig.y)

  } else if (i == 3) {
    player.setPosition(this.cards[1].x - cardsMarginX, sharedCardsConfig.y)
  }
}
this.tweenAs(this.cards[0], this.cards[2], this.cards[3])
```

}

Comment: I'd be surprised, if the used framework doesn't contain support for scaling. If it doesn't, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries

Comment: Did you checkout this part of the documentation: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.ScaleManager.html especially with the game `config`.  `Phaser.Scale.FIT` or `Phaser.Scale.RESIZE`

Comment: The resize give you ability to resize the scene it self and then you need to enhance the rest of items such as the code above, scale.fit didnt help

Comment: If possible, everything should be inside of one html div, and then you can resize that one div using css transformations. As far as a I can tell you probably should not set the world to the innerWidth/Height that is the kind of thing you could do on the one containing div.